# How to destroy and reinstall a Gem after migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I would like to know how I can destroy a gem completely and reinstall it.

This is what I did to install a gem called 'spree_fancy':

```
$bundle install 
$bundle exec rails g spree_fancy:install
```

And resulted following:

```
bundle exec rails g spree_appa:install 

append  app/assets/javascripts/store/all.js
      append  app/assets/javascripts/admin/all.js
      insert  app/assets/stylesheets/store/all.css
      insert  app/assets/stylesheets/admin/all.css
         run  bundle exec rake railties:install:migrations FROM=spree_appa from "."
Copied migration 20140105025133_add_slider_taxons_and_apply_them.spree_appa.rb from spree_appa
Would you like to run the migrations now? [Y/n] y
         run  bundle exec rake db:migrate from "."

==  AddSliderTaxonsAndApplyThem: migrating ====================================
==  AddSliderTaxonsAndApplyThem: migrated (0.3630s) ===========================
```

I have tried couple of different methods but didn't work:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:rollback
$ rails destroy controller user_controller(controllerName)
```

I didn't destroy model, because the gem I'm using is a theme for Spree Commerce and doesn't include any model. I'm not sure how I can destroy a gem after I migrated bunch of files.

Comment: I suspect your only option is to `git checkout` a previous version. The installer appended a bunch of code to a bunch of files, you can't undo that except via version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do to remove all the changes of doing `rails g spree_fancy:install`:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:rollback
$ rails destroy spree_fancy:install
```

The commands above will rollback the latest migrations you did to your schema and then destroy all files generated by the `spree_fancy:install` command.

You could also remove `gem 'spree_fancy'` from your Gemfile and then do `bundle install` if you think it necessary.

To reinstall, just do the same commands you did before.